# Using the chain rule to find partial derivatives

Tags: partial-derivative

Use the Chain Rule to find $∂z/∂s$ and $∂z/∂t$.

$$
z = \tan(u/v)
$$
$$
u = 5s + 7t
$$
$$
v = 7s − 5t
$$

This is the equation I used to find ∂z/∂s:

$$
\frac{\partial z}{\partial s}=\frac{\partial z}{\partial u}\cdot\frac{\partial u}{\partial s}+\frac{\partial z}{\partial v}\cdot\frac{\partial v}{\partial s}
$$

Before substituting for $u$ and $v$, I had simplified to:

$$
\frac{\partial z}{\partial s}=\sec^2{\frac{u}{v}}\cdot(5-7\frac{u}{v^2})
$$

However, I can't see how I'll be able to get the equation in terms of $s$. Both $u$ and $v$ are functions on $s$ **and** $t$.

Comment: Why are you not allowed to have $t$ in your answer?

Comment: I think you want $\frac{5}{v}$ instead of 5, and now you just want to substitute for u and v.

Comment: I don't know enough to fully answer your question. However, there are several worked examples in my textbook that perform chain rule partial derivations that still have both variables within the answer

Answer (score 0):

why dz/ds should have function of s only?you have two independent variable and answer can be function of both of them.for better realize suppose we have a shape in x-y plane and we we know its velocity in cartesian coordinate now you want to obtain its velocity on polar coordinate we expect velocity for example in direction of radius have two Components.i hope you realized my sample.
(sorry for my bad english)

Comment: this is answer of question and my question isn't really question its Interrogative denial:D